# How to install rpm file along with its all dependencies?

Tags: linux, installation, rpm, rhel-6

I'm trying to install `HPCC` on RHEL based machine.

I have one `.rpm` file and to install this rpm, I'm using following command:

```
sudo rpm -Uvh hpccsystems-platform_community-4.0.0-9.el6.x86_64.rpm
```

I'm getting following error :

```
error: Failed dependencies:
        boost-regex is needed by hpccsystems-platform-community-4.0.09.x86_64
        expect is needed by hpccsystems-platform-community-4.0.09.x86_64
        gcc-c++ is needed by hpccsystems-platform-community-4.0.09.x86_64
        libapr-1.so.0()(64bit) is needed by hpccsystems-platform-community-4.0.09.x86_64
        libaprutil-1.so.0()(64bit) is needed by hpccsystems-platform-community-4.0.09.x86_64
        libarchive is needed by hpccsystems-platform-community-4.0.09.x86_64
        liblber-2.4.so.2()(64bit) is needed by hpccsystems-platform-community-4.0.09.x86_64
        libldap_r-2.4.so.2()(64bit) is needed by hpccsystems-platform-community-4.0.09.x86_64
        libssl.so.10()(64bit) is needed by hpccsystems-platform-community-4.0.09.x86_64
4.0.09.x86_64
```

Please note that **this is the first time I am using RHEL**. I have used Ubuntu and in Ubuntu it was easier to install software using `apt-get install` command which fetches software along with its dependencies.

How to install this `rpm` and automatically install its all dependencies too?

Comment: If you were to compare RHEL to debian, `apt-get` becomes `yum`, and `dpkg` becomes `rpm`

Answer (score 35):

[Use yum instead.](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Deployment_Guide/ch-yum.html)

```
yum localinstall ...
```

For example:

```
yum localinstall http://pkgs.repoforge.org/subversion/subversion-devel-1.7.1-0.1.el6.rfx.i686.rpm
```

The example above will install the rpm and its dependencies automatically.

Comment: @Shekhar this is your answer...

Comment: This is not an answer as people go for rpm install and face dependency problem "because" they have no local repo or yum repo.

Answer (score 5):

you may make local yum repository and then run command

> yum install hpccsystems-platform_community-4.0.0-9.el6.x86_64.rpm

or find the online repository where this package is available and then put the url in baseurl in .repo file.

Answer (score 1):

You can enable the EPEL Repository in RHEL - download the epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm package using wget and then install it using rpm:

wget http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/x86_64/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm
rpm -ivh epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm

Then, execute the following command:

yum install gcc-c++ gcc make bison flex binutils-devel openldap-devel libicu-devel libxslt-devel libarchive-devel boost-devel openssl-devel apr-devel apr-util-devel

Finally, install the hpccsystems-platform package:

rpm -Uvh hpccsystems-platform_community-4.0.0-9.el6.x86_64.rpm